# Perl search and replace a directories

Tags: perl

I have a script where I am reading a file in hash and using one of the values as a search `$find = "pqr"` and trying to replace with a directory structure `$replace = "/abc/xyz/bcd"`

```
/usr/bin/perl -0777 -pi -e 's/$find/$replace/' $file
```

This doesn't work, I tried using "" quotes - no success

Please let me know if there some quick suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If your $replace contains slashes, use a different separator (and double quotes):

```
"s%$find%$replace%"
```